# QtConcurrent::mapped() загрузка ядра

Tags: c++, qt

Есть массив путей к файлам, к этому массиву через `mapped()` применяется некоторая функция с чтением внутри. Запустил на сервере(Xeon E5335) на большом количестве файлов и вижу интересную картину в диспетчере задач: загружено только одно ядро на 100%, остальные 5-15%. Программа использовала 12 потоков.
Это нормально или нет? Документацию листал, но ничего по своему вопросу что-то не нашел.

Comment: Вероятно, тормозит чтение данных с диска (файловая система, шины, диски). Измерьте скорость чтения данных, и скорость обработки на одном процессоре данных уже прочитанных в память.

Comment: Очень может быть, файлы берутся с HDD переносного.
Скорость обработки выше чем в однопотоке безусловно, но сам факт загрузки одного ядра из 8 удивил.
Возможности загрузить файлы в оперативу сразу все нет - 300 ГБ данных...